# Help with real world TDD using Java

Tags: java, tdd

I'm looking for help on now to use TDD for a real world example. Most show are too simple and don't really show how test and re-factor more complicated classes. Here is an example of code that uses both a thread and a network socket. Could someone explain how to create a isolated Unit Test for such a class? Thanks.

```
public class BaseHandler  extends Thread {
  protected Socket mClientSocket;
  protected BufferedReader is = null;
  protected BufferedWriter os = null;
  private Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(WebTestController.class.getName());
  protected WebTestController mWebTestController;

  /*********************************************************************
   * 
   * @param piPort - int port to listen on
   */
  public BaseHandler(){
  }


  /*********************************************************************** cleanup
   * Ensure sockets are closed as to not run into bind errors
   */
  protected void cleanup() {
    try {
      if (is != null)
        is.close();
      if (os != null)
        os.close();
      if (mClientSocket != null)
        mClientSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mLogger.info("cleaning up a socket");
  }

  /***********************************************************************************
   * Sends a message to the current socket
   * @param pMessage
   */
  protected void writeToSocket(String pMessage){
      try {
          os = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(mClientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          cleanup();
          return;
        }
        try {
            os.write(pMessage, 0, pMessage.length());
            os.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cleanup();
  }

}
```

Comment: I know the feeling. Add 1 plus 1 with TDD! Silly. Puts a lot of people off TDD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a couple of practical things to do to reduce your testing issues:

1. Don't have your class inherit Thread. Make it a Runnable instead, because you can test a Runnable in isolation.
2. Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) so that you can replace the Logger and the WebTestController with test versions (see "mocking").
3. Remove anything from your code that doesn't do anything yet. Then test what you have. Add new stuff only when everything you have implemented is working and has valid tests to prove it

However I strongly recommend reading a good book about TDD and unit testing. The simple tutorials are just that - simple. They don't cover the complicated cases that you will run into in real life. It's perfectly possible to use TDD in real life, but it does take some knowledge - just like programming.

Comment: The class doesn't even have to be Runnable, there are many features of this class which don't do anything.  I still suggest he start with a simple test case he expects to work, start the class from scratch and only add the code which is needed to pass the tests.

Answer (score 5):

Don't create such classes.

It would be better to break your logic into IO-related part and concurrency-related part. Then IO-related part can be tested, for example, with a mock socket implementation.

Testing concurrency-related logic would be more complex, though. It depends on behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: +1: Though I would just use a real Socket rather than a mock of one.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you should start with the Test case in Test Drive Development. I suggest you start with the test this class should pass first and treat this as a prototype.

You will have to create a class or sub-class which will open a Socket to a dummy ServerSocket and send messages to it.

Comment: You still have to do design, and you can't even write your tests until you know what classes and methods you are going to write: so this advice doesn't really get you anywhere

Comment: The OP was asking about TDD. You cannot complete the design without completing the tests so I don't think your distinction is relevant in TDD.

Comment: In TDD before you write the tests you have to decide what you are testing. Even using TDD iteratively you have to decide the first class, and the first method, that you are going to create before you can write the test - otherwise what is the test going to call?

Comment: In TDD the design and the test are one in the first stage. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development "first the developer writes a failing automated test case that defines a desired improvement or new function"  There is no separate design stage before this.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't "use" a thread, it's just a class derived from `java.lang.Thread`. Nothing stops you from calling the `run()` method directly, after all you're testing your class and not the functionality in `java.lang.Thread`.

In fact you want to test the `cleanup()` and `writeToSocket` methods, so there's no need to call the `run()` method either.

Just create a subclass of `BaseHandler`, initialize your members in that subclass with some mock objects and you're good to go.

You may need other changes to make the rest of your code easier to test, though. I'm assuming this question is more about unit testing an existing code base and less about TDD.

Comment: +1: The `run()` method is inherited from Thread so it doesn't do anything. ;)

Comment: It is both since I need to adjust my thinking and development style to work with TDD. I posed this question to learn how based on what I currently do.

Answer (score 1):

This class doesn't respect SRP(Single Responsibility Priciple). Your class does too much logic. 
Instead you should split this class into multiple smaller ones. You usually then inject those classes with Spring or other IoC framework.

If you were to split the class you would notice that it will be much easier to test. You could supply mock objects for those components and inject them as you wish in each test case, as it suits you best.